# Pass useState function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to pass a useState `setState` function to a custom component. Every option that I've tried so far has failed.

This is where I call my custom component:

```
const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(true);

<DisclaimerModal
     text='...'
     showDialog={showDialog}
     handleAccept={setShowDialog(false)}
     handleDecline={setShowDialog(false)}
/>
```

And this is my custom component:

```
interface DisclaimerModalProps extends ViewProps {
    text: string,
    showDialog: boolean,
    handleAccept: () => void,
    handleDecline: () => void
}

export function DisclaimerModal({ text, showDialog, handleAccept, handleDecline }: DisclaimerModalProps): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Modal
            visible={showDialog}
            transparent
        >
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.textDisclaimer}>{text}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.modalRow}>
                            <Text
                                onPress={() => { handleDecline }}
                            >
                                Cancel
                            </Text>
                            <Text
                                onPress={() => { handleAccept }}
                            >
                                Accept
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

How can I pass the `useState` function as a prop? As you can see, the last thing I tried was to pass the whole function, however, this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `setState` straight away and returning the result (which is probably undefined, the setter doesnt return anything) to the prop. What you actually want to do is to provide a function which calls the setter.

```
const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(true);

<DisclaimerModal
     text='...'
     showDialog={showDialog}
     handleAccept={() => setShowDialog(false)}
     handleDecline={() => setShowDialog(false)}
/>
```

And then in the consuming component, call the function you just passed.

```
interface DisclaimerModalProps extends ViewProps {
    text: string,
    showDialog: boolean,
    handleAccept: () => void,
    handleDecline: () => void
}

export function DisclaimerModal({ text, showDialog, handleAccept, handleDecline }: DisclaimerModalProps): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Modal
            visible={showDialog}
            transparent
        >
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.textDisclaimer}>{text}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.modalRow}>
                            <Text
                                onPress={() => { handleDecline() }}
                            >
                                Cancel
                            </Text>
                            <Text
                                onPress={() => { handleAccept() }}
                            >
                                Accept
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Comment: Or simpler: `onPress={handleDecline}`.